# Linear programming: Check if this base is feasible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

I have an LP:
$$
\max z:     5x1 + 12x2 +4x3
$$
s.t
$$ x1 +   2x2 +x3 + x4 =  10$$
$$2x1 +  -2x2 -x3 = 2 $$

I want to check some bases if they are feasible. For $B=(P_1 P_2)$ I did:
$B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & -2 
\end{pmatrix} \implies 
B^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2 \\
-2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then I do :

$B^{-1}b=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2 \\
-2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
10  \\
2 
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
-24  \\
-18 
\end{pmatrix}
$

The criterion for B to be feasible is $B^{-1}b\geq 0$ which here does not hold.

But I put the LP in this solver https://online-optimizer.appspot.com/?model=ms:DczwN3ywZ0U6jycl9NOAEMqlkw0Wzzib and $x_1, x_2$ is an optimal base

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: your $B^{-1}$ is computed wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$B^{-1} = \frac16\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$B^{-1}\cdot (10, 2)^T = (4, 3)^T > 0$$